# Spring resource loading fails on "specific" context paths

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a weird situation. My static resources (images,icons,css,js etc) in Spring Boot and Security based project load just fine at some context paths but wont work on others. 
For example the below works just fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/appUserProfile/1
```

But for this, resources wont load:

```
http://localhost:8080/appUserProfile/1/image
```

For above, I have tried all of the following in my mvc config:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/appUserProfile**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/appUserProfile/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/appUserProfile/**/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/appUserProfile/*/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/appUserProfile/*/*").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

**In addition to above** the same thing happens whenever I encounter access-denied. **My custom 403 page load just fine but the resources would not load**.

Questions:

1. Why it works for /appUserProfile/1 and not for /appUserProfile/1/image? What I am missing here and/or what is wrong here?
2. What can be done to load resources in access-denied page? Are both of these related or any special configuration required for this very special page?

Here are my full [security](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootFlashy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebSecurity.java) and [mvcConfig](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootFlashy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebMVC.java) classes in case above provided information is not enough.

**Update:**

I am not using any context path in application.properties. Posting the proj structure screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the context path using the `application.properties` like : `server.servlet.context-path=/appUserProfile`. If yes , then your assets will be served from the url : `http://localhost:8080/appUserProfile/1/image`  even if you keep it in your static folder without any sub folder structure. How are you handling your endpoints like :

```
http://localhost:8080/appUserProfile/1
```

The `/appUserProfile` path might be provided as a request mapping at the controller level by you most probably right. What you can do it remove this controller level mapping, add the context path to the `application.properties` like I provided and keep the assets in the `static` folder. If not, provide more details in the question like folder structure, your context mapping, controller details for furthur analysis.

Comment: Thanks @Ananthapadmanabhan for your effort. But it was a silly mistake from my side. I was missing leading forward slash for image path. i.e. img/abc.png instead of /img/abc.png. After adding leading forward slashes to images, fixed it all. Now I am not sure if I should delete this question or not so that I do not create confusion for others and waste their time. My apologies.